# Null object returned from repository in spring boot unit test for service layer save method

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm currently working on writing unit tests for a Spring Boot application. Specifically, I'm trying to write a unit test for the save method in the service layer. However, when I call the save method, the object returned from the repository is coming back as null. Here's what my test code looks like...

```
   public TodoResponse addTodo(TodoRequest todoRequest) {
        Todo todo = modelMapper.map(todoRequest, Todo.class);
        Todo savedTodo = todoRepos.save(todo);
        TodoResponse todoResponse = modelMapper.map(savedTodo, TodoResponse.class);
        return todoResponse;
    }
```

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TodoServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private TodoService cut;

    @Mock
    private TodoRepository todoRepos;


  @Test
    @DisplayName("Test add todo")
    void should_add_todo() {

        TodoRequest todoRequest = new TodoRequest();
        todoRequest.setTitle("someValue");
        todoRequest.setDescription("someValue");
        todoRequest.setCompleted(false);

        Todo todo = new Todo(1L, todoRequest.getTitle(), todoRequest.getDescription(), todoRequest.isCompleted());

        when(modelMapper.map(todoRequest, Todo.class)).thenReturn(todo);
        when(todoRepos.save(todo)).thenReturn(todo);
        TodoResponse todoResponse = new TodoResponse();
        when(modelMapper.map(todo, TodoResponse.class)).thenReturn(todoResponse);

        TodoResponse result = cut.addTodo(todoRequest);
        verify(modelMapper).map(todoRequest, Todo.class);
        verify(todoRepos).save(todo);
        verify(modelMapper).map(todo, TodoResponse.class);

        assertNotNull(result);
        assertNotNull(result.getDescription());
        assertNotNull(result.getTitle());
        assertNotNull(result.isCompleted());
        assertEquals(todoRequest.getTitle(), result.getTitle());
        assertEquals(todoRequest.getDescription(), result.getDescription());
        assertEquals(todoRequest.isCompleted(), result.isCompleted());

    }
}
```

I've checked my mock setups and ensured that I'm correctly mocking the repository's save method. I'm also providing valid input to the service method. Despite these efforts, I'm consistently getting a null object returned from the repository.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue while writing unit tests for Spring Boot services? Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this unexpected behavior and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to use `@MockBean` instead of `Mock` ?

Comment: and also replace `@InjectsMocks` from you service to `@Autowired` because you are doing integration tests `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: Either use `@SpringBootTest` with `@MockBean` and `@Autowired`, or `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` with `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`. Those annotations are not equivalent and mutually exclusive (most of the time)

Comment: still not working